# How does Linux decide which executable I'm trying to run?

Tags: linux, path

I thought I understood this, but I'm getting unexplained behavior. I have these files:

```
$ which -a kvm | xargs ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 2011-11-17 17:14 /usr/bin/kvm -> qemu-system-x86_64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 2011-11-17 17:21 /usr/local/bin/kvm -> qemu-system-x86_64
$ which -a qemu-system-x86_64 | xargs ls -l
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2535168 2011-10-04 02:44 /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3497304 2011-11-17 16:26 /usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64
```

And they are different versions:

```
$ /usr/bin/kvm --version
QEMU PC emulator version 0.12.3 (qemu-kvm-0.12.3), Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard
$ /usr/local/bin/kvm --version
QEMU emulator version 0.15.92 (qemu-kvm-devel), Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard
```

My path has `/usr/local/bin` first, and when I do `which` I see that one. So I'd expect it to win. But instead the older version wins:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
$ which kvm
/usr/local/bin/kvm
$ kvm --version
QEMU PC emulator version 0.12.3 (qemu-kvm-0.12.3), Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard
```

Why does `kvm --version` give me 0.12 instead of 0.15???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Linux does not make the decision in this case; it's supplied with the exact path by your shell. When using advanced shells such as *bash* or *zsh*, the `which` tool is inaccurate since it only checks $PATH, but there are several more possibilities. Running `type kvm` should tell you where the shell is looking for it.

- "`hashed`": The first time you run a command, the *bash* shell remembers its location so that it won't have to search the entire $PATH again. The remembered locations are only kept in memory. Use `hash` to list them and `hash -r` to reset, or simply start a second shell window.
- "`alias`": You may have created an alias "`kvm`" pointing to the old path. If this is the case, use `unalias kvm` to remove the alias.
- "`function`": Similar to aliases, but more expressive. Again, it's possible that you have added and forgotten a function named `kvm` pointing to the wrong path. Use `unset kvm` to remove such a function.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the PATH search by declaring an alias

```
alias kvm=/sbin/kvm
```

Try `type -a kvm`

I created an alias for date

```
$ which -a date
/usr/local/bin/date
/bin/date

$ type -a date
date is aliased to `/bin/date'
date is /usr/local/bin/date
date is /bin/date
```